# How to print out the first 4 bytes from stdin

Tags: c++, io, binary, dataformat

I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::freopen(nullptr, "rb", stdin);
    char buf[4];
    std::fread(buf, 1, 4, stdin);
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

Which, I think, does the following.

1. reopens stdin to read bytes
2. Init a char buffer array of size 4
3. read into buf one byte at the time
4. for a total of 4 bytes
5. read from stdin
6. print out content of buf

I have a file, `test`, which contains this `4s���K$d877cc15-9569-4880-aea6-64a0466ebf3ch�`

And `file -bi test` gives `application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

And when I do

```
cat test | main
```

I get nothing.

But if I create a file `test2` containing `test123`. And do:

```
cat test2 | main
```

I get: `test` as expected.

So this leads me to think that I somehow fail to read binary input.

What could my problem be?

Comment: What are the four byte values you expect to read from binary input file? What happens if you init the array to them (skip) the file reading and then output the buffer the same way? If that works you have narrowed the problem down to reading. If it fails it is about outputting.

Comment: What exactlx do you expect as output of four (presumably) non-printable-ascii values, if you output them as four `char`s?

Comment: `std::cout << +buf[0] << " " << +buf[1] << " " << +buf[2] << " " << +buf[3] << std::endl;`

Comment: Why not simply [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) four bytes directly from `std::cin`?

Comment: As for your problem, writing any `char` type to `std::cout` using the `<<` operator will print it as *characters*. You need to convert the values to (unsigned) integers. Either as shown in the comment by @Eljay, or using `static_cast` (as in `static_cast<unsigned>(buf[0])`)

Comment: @Yunnosch This is not exactly my scenario.

Comment: @Eljay Thank you! What is this syntax `+buf[0]` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since read is by default in text-mode, and will not work with binary values. But yea, it seems like I was simply printing it out incorrectly, since Eljiay's solution seemed to work!